# Start up fresh or clean instance of eclipse

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu

When using eclipse on ubuntu, for some reason it crashes/stops responding when loading an existing coffeescript project. Is there a command I can send to it when starting up to load a fresh instance, no pre-loaded tabs or workspace, just the default setup? But I still need my plugins to be working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried the "-clean" argument when launching Eclipse?

Comment: I was hoping it was just something wrong with your OSGi cache.  You can also try removing the <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/.snap file if it exists before starting Eclipse.  If needed, you can also remove everything in <workspace>/.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.resources/, but you'll have to reimport all your projects into your workspace.